# File validation inside message queue module or outside

Tags: rabbitmq

I have 2 java application and they are communicating using Rabbit MQ. Here communicating meaning sending of files between 2 applications. Now I have a requirement to verify the content of the file. I am able to do that. But my question is shall I put the file validation in the message queue module or outside the message queue module? Which will be a better approach?

**As per my understanding** 
the message queue is only used for sending, receiving and temporarily storing the data and validation should not be used inside the rabbit message queue module.

Comment: Queues (in rmq) are not used for sending. What is the `message queue module` for you? There is the consumer which consumes the message and that's it. Are you talking about writing a plugin or extending RabbitMQ?

Comment: @cantSleepNow: Yes one is sending and another one is consuming . I just need to know if the file that is being consumed is validated after receiving via Rabbit MQ or it needs to be validated before putting into the queue by the sender ? The Message Queue module refers as the opening of ConnectionFactory and publishing by the sender and receiving by the Consumer.